# query results with hibernate-search with associated enumeration field

Tags: java, lucene, hibernate-search

I am trying to make document index of the Entity that has following associations:

DocVersion:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class DocVersion implements Serializable {
...
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "doc_uuid")
    @IndexedEmbedded
    private Document2 document2;
...
}
```

Document2:

```
@Entity
@Indexed
public class Document2 implements Serializable {
...
    @Column(name = "entityState")
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    @Field(bridge=@FieldBridge(impl=EnumBridge.class), index=Index.YES)
    private EDocState eDocState;
...
}
```

this is how I query the index (just for testing purposes):

```
FullTextEntityManager fullTextEntityManager = Search.getFullTextEntityManager(entityManager);
        try {
            fullTextEntityManager.createIndexer().startAndWait();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        QueryBuilder queryBuilder = fullTextEntityManager.getSearchFactory()
                .buildQueryBuilder()
                .forEntity(DocVersion.class)
                .get();

        org.apache.lucene.search.Query luceneQuery = queryBuilder.keyword()
                .onField("document2.eDocState").matching("HARD_DEL")
                .createQuery();
List results = fullTextEntityManager.createFullTextQuery(luceneQuery, DocVersion.class)
                .getResultList();
```

but instead of results I get:

```
WARNING: org.hibernate.search.bridge.BridgeException: Exception while calling bridge#objectToString
    entity class: com.nws.vedica.model.entity.DocVersion
    entity property path: document2.eDocState
    field bridge: TwoWayString2FieldBridgeAdaptor [stringBridge=org.hibernate.search.bridge.builtin.EnumBridge@60942b8b]
```

So what does that mean? Do I need to implement some specific bridge for an Enumeration (how would that look like)? 
It's just value enum so I think problem is somewhere else.

Please assist me to get the results.

package I'm using:
hibernate-search-orm: 5.9.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to implement a specific bridge, actually it's quite the opposite: a bridge is already there, so Hibernate Search expects you to pass enum values to the query, and you're passing String values instead.

Try replacing `.matching("HARD_DEL")` with `.matching(EDocState.HARD_DEL)`.

Note: I suspect the rest of the stack trace would tell you something about a class cast exception, which could have tipped you off. For your own sake, you should probably not hide stack traces like that, stack traces may contain valuable information.

Comment: yeah, that's right. don't know why I didn't try it all day long... 
maybe I need to tune my logback a little more.
thanks.